# How to save a variable value on AS3 for IOS when application is closed and reopened dont lose variable value

Tags: iphone, actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

I'm programming in Flash CC (AS3) for IOS, I wonder how do I save the score of a game, when the application is closed and reopened it was not deleted.

I'm using a simple variable to count the points. How do I not lose the value of this varialvel when the application is closed?

Comment: Store it in `NSUserDefaults` if it doesn't hold sensitive data, and in the keychain if it does.

Comment: Are you using AIR? You could use SQLLite to save data locally

Comment: I´ll try this! Give you a reply!

Comment: By the way I´m using Flash CC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either:

- Store information on a `SharedObject` (the easiest way)
- Write a local file in AMF format
- Use the SQLLite database

More info here: http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flash/articles/saving_state_air_apps.html

Comment: Very usefull! So I star trying use SharedObject. Wen the aplication hit the frame with the code below it freeze and does not give me a chance to see any error message. Any thing special that should be done for IOS?


var so:SharedObject = SharedObject.getLocal("Math");
so.data['result'] = int(so.data['result']);
so.flush();

Comment: `so.data['result'] = int(so.data['result']);` this should be `so.data['result'] = int(something);` No?

Comment: As the web site above is correct. result is the int variable that I want to store. By the way I tryied, I discovery that it freeze with just the fist line.(removing the other 2)

 var so:SharedObject = SharedObject.getLocal("Math");

Comment: That´s the point! it freeze before show any error message! I´m forced to close the Flash CC and reopen. I try intall on the device and it freeze on the same frame.

Comment: I remove AIR vibration extention and Flash CC stop chashing. Returns no error! the application runs fine on the computer it freeze only on the device.

Comment: Works fine on a 32bits computer and a not jailbreack device. Thanks all!,